# Definition of change of variables function and finding the new domain of integration.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The change of variables method was introduced in my class as the following theorem:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb R^k$ be an open set and let $g : U \to \mathbb R^k$ be a $C^1$, one-to-one function such that $Jg(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in U$.
> Let $A \subset \mathbb R^k$ be a compact set that has a finite volume, $f:A \to \mathbb R$ integrable function such that $f \circ g: g^{-1}(U) \to \mathbb R$ is integrable.
> So $g^{-1}(A)$ has finite volume and $\int_A f(x)dx = \int_{g^{-1}(A)} (f \circ g)(u) |Jg(u)|du $.

I'm having two difficulties with this:

1. I don't understand how to find the new region under $g^{-1}$. For example, if $A$ is a triangle in $\mathbb R^2$ bounded by the coordinates $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$, and the change of variables is $u = x-y, v = x+y$, what is the new region under the transformation (or, what is $g^{-1}(A)$)?
2. In the theorem a $\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^k$ function is used ($g$) for the change of variables, but I've also seen solutions with change of variables using $u,v$, like in the example above. But it seems $u$ and $v$ are $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ functions (of $x$ and $y$), so how is using $u,v$ equivalent to using $g$? In the example from the previous question, is $g$ defined as $g(x,y)=(x-y, x+y)$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in the statement you provided there is a  typo since $f \circ g: U \to \mathbb R$.

Regarding **1)**:

$A \subset \mathbb R^2$ is the following set:

$$
A={\{(x,y): 0 \leq y \leq 1-x, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1\}}  \tag{1}
$$

The trasformation and its inverse are:

$$\begin{cases}
 x=g(u,v)=(u+v)/2\\ 
 y=g(u,v)=(v-u)/2
\end{cases}  \tag{2}
$$

and

$$\begin{cases}
 u=g^{-1}(x,y)=x-y\\ 
 v=g^{-1}(x,y)=x+y 
\end{cases}  \tag{3}
$$

In order to find the *pre-image* $g^{-1}(A)$ we need to substitute $(2)$ in the inequalities in $(1)$. Doing so we obtain:

$$\begin{cases}
 0 \leq v-u \leq 2 - (u+v) \\ 
 0 \leq (u +v) \leq 2
\end{cases}  \tag{4}
$$

The system above defines in the $(u,v)$ plane a triangle bounded by the points $(0,0), (-1,1), (1,1)$ as you can see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dfo9f35trg).

Regarding **2)**     I hope it's clear from the above discussion how $(u,v)$ are related to $g$.